# How to describe algorithms when doing Use Cases?

Tags: oop, uml, use-case

Let's say I'm making an `Use Case` for a game that has a scoring system. Each action you do in the game will increase/decrease your score in the game.

Here is a sketch of my `Use Case`:

```
1. ...
2. ...
...
8. The Player makes (some move).
9. The System registers the play and calculates his new score.
```

There is some algorithm behind calculating this new score. Should I state it in this `Use Case`? Should I state it in another `Use Case`? Should I simply omit the details of implementation of the algorithm?

Is the `Use Case` the correct place to state those kinds of things? Or should the `Use Case` just be concerned with the interactions between the `Player` and the `System`(the `Game`)?

I'd say I'd probably want to write down those details somewhere (if not just to make sure I really do understand them). So it looks to me maybe the best option is to make another Use Case where I describe how they work?

How are generally these kind of things done with `Use Cases`? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algorithms are *not* interaction between user and system to create something of value.

They're a footnote or an appendix to the use case.

They're often important, but they're not interaction.  Hence putting them in an appendix.

---

Also.  All use cases are initiated by the Actor.  They actor wants to play they game; they initiate things.  The system generally can't initiate action -- it's passive, responding to the actor.

Comment: Another question. When the game starts the current score is set to zero. Should I define an operation that states that or not? From what I've understood from your answer, I'd say no.

Comment: I can argue it both ways.  I don't see any harm in saying "The System starts a new game with score set to 0"

Comment: Also, does it make any sense to start a Use Case with the System sending the first message?

Comment: Actors initiate use cases.  Period.  The Actor starts the game.  The game responds to the Actor

Comment: If a system ever called me up and asked me to play, I'd change my medication!

Answer (score 3):

Algorithms don't belong in use cases.  Extract them to a business rules section or document.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Activity Diagram to represent algorithms and leave your Use Case steps simple in this case. 
I also  agree with "Johann Strydom" in his position.

Leo